# Feynmp/auto not working in Yosemite?

Tags: mac, texshop, feynmf, feynmp-auto

So I've used feynmp and feynmp-auto hundreds of times, but now it seems neither is working on Mac OS Yosemite. I have installed both and when run I get messages like:

I run this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\unitlength = 1mm
    \begin{fmffile}{Test}
    \begin{fmfgraph}(40,15)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v3,i2}
    \fmf{photon,tension=0}{v1,v3}
    \fmf{photon,tension=0}{v2,v4}
    \end{fmfgraph}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

And get this error

```
feynmp: File Test.1 not found:
feynmp: Process Test.mp with MetaPost and then reprocess this file.
```

**Update:** for some reason, when I include the following code (together with relevant packages if any) everything works fine:

```
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi
  \IfFileExists{\thefmffile.mp}{\immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}}{}
  \let\thefmffile\relax
}
\makeatother
```

I thought feynmp-auto took care of that last problem.

I use TexShop newest version, but I think my TexLive is from 2013.

Comment: Can you find some `runsystem` entry in the log file?

Comment: I think I know how to solve it. The reason for the question is that I don't want to reuse old tex files (which I somehow got to work in the past) because they are slow (I load tens of packages). Now I'm looking through an old Tex file and it looks like I've found a piece of code that solves the problem. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Do you think that the following code might have anything to do with the fact that it works if it is included (toghether with relevant packages)? 
<
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi
  \IfFileExists{\thefmffile.mp}{\immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}}{}
  \let\thefmffile\relax
}
\makeatother >

Comment: Yes, of course it has to do with the problem! It's the code `feynmp-auto` was built upon! Loading `feynmp-auto` with that code is a good way to break everything. ;-)

Comment: Break everything? I don't understand? It works when the code is included. Btw how write codes in comments?

Comment: Try adding the `force` option: `\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}` in order to reset everything.

Comment: Yes I tried that one.

Comment: TeX Live 2013? No, no.

Comment: I guess I kind of took for granted that TeXLive should autoupdate.

Comment: You can also use MacTeX, which is available in a [2014 version](https://tug.org/mactex/). Code in text, i.e. in comments and in a post, can be written by using backticks: \`x\` yields `x`.

Comment: @Faq what is the status of this question?